# How do I catch exceptions that have specific error messages in Python?

Tags: python, exception

When I have two Python exceptions that are the same exception class but a different error message, how do I catch them separately?

For specific use-case: 
I'm using the [Facepy library](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) to hit the Facebook Graph API. When the API returns an error that isn't Oauth related, Facepy raises a `facepy.exceptions.FacebookError` and passes the error message given by the Facebook API.

I'm consistently hitting two different errors that I'd like to treat differently and the only way to parse them is the error message, but I can't figure out how to write my `except` clause--here it is in pseudo-code:

```
try: 
    #api query

except facepy.exceptions.OAuthError and error_message = 'object does not exist':
    # do something

except facepy.exceptions.OAuthError and error_message = 'Hit API rate limit':
    # do something else
```

How do I write these `except` clauses to trigger off both the exception and the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`facepy`'s `OAuthError` derives from `FacebookError` and that has `message` attribute. https://github.com/jgorset/facepy/blob/master/facepy/exceptions.py#L8. So, you can use `if` condition with the `message` like this

```
try:
    #api query
except facepy.exceptions.OAuthError as error:
    if 'object does not exist' == error.message:
       # do something
    elif 'Hit API rate limit' == error.message:
       # do something else
    else:
       raise
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look up this specific library. Appreciated you saving me time here.

Comment: You should do as Thomas Orozco notes and `raise` if the message does not match either of those.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks Daniel :) I updated my answer as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the Exception's error message is in the `error_message` attribute (it may be something else — look at the Exception's `__dict__` or source to find out):

```
try: 
    #api query

except facepy.exceptions.OAuthError as e:
    if e.error_message == "object does not exist":
        print "Do X"
    elif e.error_message == "Hit API rate limit":
        print "Do Y"
    else:
        raise
```